# How can I protect my Chainlink oracle fulfill method?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, oracles, chainlink

**Background:**

I'm writing a contract that inherits `ChainlinkClient` in order to make an API request via an oracle job:

```
function fetch() private returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
    request.add("get", ...);
    return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
}

function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _result) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
    // Rely on returned data
}
```

**Assumptions:**

- When making an oracle request, the `fulfill` method must be `public`.
- `public` methods may be accessed by any other contract.

**Question:**

What prevents someone manually calling the `fulfill` method? This is relevant because the contract relies on the data injected in `fulfill`.

How are contracts secured from injection of invalid data? I expect this question is a result of my own misunderstanding of how oracle interactions work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct, it needs to be public but modifiers can help in this case. ChainlinkClient has `recordchainlinkfulfillment` modifier for fulfillment callbacks.

This modifier specifies that only the original oracle that was called may call this function, the oracle defined when you send the request.

Reference: [chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-framework#recordchainlinkfulfillment)